# Weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;V)$ implies weak convergence a.e.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, bochner-spaces

There is a popular result, which proves, that strong convergence in $L^2(0,T;V)$ implies strong convergence almost everywhere in $[0,T]$.

Is there an analoguous result for weak convergence? Thanks, FFoDWindow

Comment: The typical example of sequence weakly converging to zero but not strongly is $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$, which does not converge a.e., even up to subsequences

Comment: Maybe you understood my question wrong. I was asking, if weak convergence in $L^2(0,T;V)$ implies weak convergence a.e. in $V$ ?

Comment: Oh sorry. Now I see that the functions are $V$-valued. In any case, if $V=\mathbb R$ then strong and weak convergence coincide with the usual convergence of real numbers, so does the same example work?

Comment: Yeah, this counterexample holds. Unfortunately. Thank you!